# MicroStrategy add two conditions in IF statement

Tags: microstrategy

I want to create a new Metric, using MicroStrategy Metric Editor, to check two conditions:

```
1 is progress_days > complete_date
2 is Status column is = In Progress
```

if both conditions are met, then Red, else Green

[image]

it looks like MicroStrategy doesn't support it, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your two conditions in an `And` function.

Answer (score 0):

what I find out today is I can't mix a metric with a attribute in the AND logic, and I need to use double quote instead of single quote.

use single Case statement can handle 2 or more conditions

```
Case(((today@ID>[Due Date]@ID)And(Status@ID="Done")), "Green", ((today@ID>[Due Date]@ID)And(Status@ID="In Progress")), "Red", "Progress")
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between Case and If

The If function is very similar to the Case function. Each function takes a condition as an argument and returns a value depending on whether the condition is true or not. The Case function can evaluate multiple conditional arguments, while the If function can only evaluate one condition.